# Present GameCenter authenticationVC again

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm facing a little issue here and I hope someone will help me figure out what is wrong.

*The test project presented below can be find here : http://goo.gl/wz84aA (FR) or https://goo.gl/0m8LrZ (Mega.NZ) *

I'm trying to present to the user the authentification view controller proposed by apple for the GameCenter feature. More precisely, re-present it if he canceled it on the first time.

I have a game with a storyboard like that :

[image: Storyboard]

GameNavigationController :

```
class GameNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("showAuthenticationViewController"), name: PresentAuthenticationViewController, object: nil)

        GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.authenticateLocalPlayer()
    }

    func showAuthenticationViewController() {
        let gameKitHelper = GameKitHelper.sharedInstance

        if let authenticationViewController = gameKitHelper.authenticationViewController {
            self.topViewController.presentViewController(authenticationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

MenuViewController :

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func didTapLeaderboardBTN() {
        // TRY 2
        //if ( !GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.gameCenterEnabled) {
            GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.authenticateLocalPlayer()
        //} else {
            GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.showGKGameCenterViewController(self)
        //}
    }
}
```

GameKitHelper :

```
import GameKit
import Foundation

let PresentAuthenticationViewController = "PresentAuthenticationViewController"

let singleton = GameKitHelper()

class GameKitHelper: NSObject, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

    var authenticationViewController: UIViewController?
    var lastError: NSError?
    var gameCenterEnabled: Bool

    class var sharedInstance: GameKitHelper {
        return singleton
    }

    override init() {
        gameCenterEnabled = true
        super.init()
    }

    func authenticateLocalPlayer () {

        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { (viewController, error) in

            self.lastError = error

            if viewController != nil {
                self.authenticationViewController = viewController
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(PresentAuthenticationViewController, object: self)
            } else if localPlayer.authenticated {
                self.gameCenterEnabled = true
            } else {
                self.gameCenterEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    func showGKGameCenterViewController(viewController: UIViewController!) {

        if ( !self.gameCenterEnabled ) {
            println("Local player is not authenticated")

            // TRY 1
            //self.authenticateLocalPlayer()

            return
        }

        let gameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()

        gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

        gameCenterViewController.viewState = .Leaderboards

        viewController.presentViewController(gameCenterViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What is currently working :

- if the user is previously logged-in (within the GameCenter app) then he's able to open the leaderboard view ;
- if the user wasn't logged-in then he's prompted to log-in when the game navigation controller is loaded (and then open the leaderboard).

What is NOT currently working :

- if he cancel three time the authentification, then the authentification won't appear anymore (even at launch) ; *// Apparently a known "problem", not "fixable"*
- if the user cancel his authentification, when he tries to load the leaderboard the authentification won't appear again.

I tried 2-3 things as you can see in the commented code above, but none of them is working ; I can't make the authentification view appear again.

PS : My code is written in Swift, but help in Objective-C is welcomed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have found out, if the Game Center authentication dialog is canceled 3 times, then you can't bring it back without resetting the device.

There is another "security feature" built into Game Center which does not allow an app to re-authenticate if the user has already canceled the dialog without leaving the app. So for your authentication dialog to show, the user must leave and then re-enter your app.

There is really no way around it. What I've done in a couple of projects is to display a message to the user:

`Game Center not available. Please make sure you are signed in through the Game Center app`

I will show that message after trying to authenticate and if Game Center isn't available or the user is not signed in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to re-present this to your user then go to settings -> General -> Reset -> -> Reset Location & Privacy.

[image]

This will force iOS to forget preferences for apps for example whether they can use location services, send you push notifications and also game centre preferences. Keep in mind this will reset privacy settings for all apps.